# Wrong value is returned when calling a function from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

First post yall.

Long story short, in Excel, when I call the following function (it's in its own module) from a cell, it returns the wrong value.  The function returns the correct value when calling it from a sub, as well as when I step through the code (to the end), but the moment I call it from Excel, it returns a different value. Background at the bottom.

**Things I've Tried**

- Making it a Public Function
- Giving it an argument
- Changing the function and/or module name
- Moving it out of a module
- Restarting Excel
- A bunch of random stuff

It really is just this specific function that's giving me this issue, simpler functions do what they're told. I have to assume it has something to do with the order of events Excel is doing things, or the limits of what parts of Excel a function can change.

```
Function ActiveDisciplineFilters()

    Application.Volatile 'makes the function update automatically
    Dim disccolumn As Range
    Dim uniquedisc() As String
    Dim uniquediscstring As String

    'create a string of unique values from the Discipline column
    i = 0
    If Range("LayerList[Discipline]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address = Range("LayerList[Discipline]").Address Then
        ActiveDisciplineFilters = "None"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For Each cell In Range("LayerList[Discipline]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If InStr(1, uniquediscstring, cell.Value) = 0 Then
            If i <> 0 Then
                uniquediscstring = uniquediscstring & ", " & cell.Value
            Else
                uniquediscstring = cell.Value
                i = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ActiveDisciplineFilters = uniquediscstring

End Function
```

**Background**

In Excel, I have a table. I'm taking all the data in one specific column of that table and creating a string of the unique values in that range (separated by comma). That string must be placed in another cell, for reasons I don't need to get into. If a filter is applied to the column, the unique values update automatically.

*What would make Excel give me the right answer when I call it from a sub, then the wrong one when I call it from a cell?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the SpecialCells methods work in a UDF.  If you need this to be run from the worksheet as a formula, then your code should look like this instead:

```
Function ActiveDisciplineFilters()

    Application.Volatile 'makes the function update automatically
    Dim disccolumn As Range
    Dim uniquedisc() As String
    Dim uniquediscstring As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim bHidden As Boolean

    'create a string of unique values from the Discipline column
    i = 0

    For Each cell In Range("LayerList[Discipline]").Cells
        If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If InStr(1, uniquediscstring, cell.Value) = 0 Then
                If i <> 0 Then
                    uniquediscstring = uniquediscstring & ", " & cell.Value
                Else
                    uniquediscstring = cell.Value
                    i = 1
                End If
            End If
        Else
            bHidden = True
        End If
    Next

    If Not bHidden Then uniquediscstring = "None"
    ActiveDisciplineFilters = uniquediscstring

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you kind internet person. This does exactly what I'd hoped.